# Find current active connections given connection and disconnection times of a location

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas-timeindex

I have a dataframe that has **connection date**, **disconnection date**, **rowID** and **RouterName**. I want to find the current active connections in a while loop which iterates every minutes(this can be changed to any minutes) for 24 hours. I am trying to calculate the count of people in the location from this dataset which i will later use for calculating the agents risk level of being infected with corona or any airborne infectious disease. I cant find a way to calculate this from dataset using python pandas.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I’m going to make a few assumptions:

1. every device Id is unique and there are no collisions
2. you are looking only for devices which are currently connected
3. a connected device has a null disconnect_at

   active = df[df.disconnect_at < curr_timestamp]
   counts = active.groupby(“router_name”).agg({“device_id”:pd.Series.nunique})

Something like this should work

Comment: 1. every device id is unique but they might appear in somewhere else in the dataframe. 2. Yes I am looking for devices that are currently connected. 3. A connected device does not have a null disconnect_at it has the disconnect timestamp.

Comment: **3. A connected device does not have a null disconnect_at it has the disconnect timestamp**
so how do you know when a device is connected? does the disconnect give the current time? or are you looking for devices with a disconnect time in the last X seconds?